# add a comment to an existing issue in gitlab

Tags: python-gitlab

with that code I can create an issue in GitLab with python-gitlab

```
    issue = project.issues.create({'title': title, 'description': description})
    issue.labels = ['label1', 'label2']
    issue.assignee_ids = username
    issue.save()
```

I did not find any possibility to add a comment to an existing issue.
Would that be possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. It is actually a bit hidden because adding a comment is actually a notes create in the python library

```
issue.notes.create({"body": "some comment"})
```